# RTK API Wrapper around Spotify Web API Node library as Cache

Tags: node.js, typescript, redux, typescript-generics, rtk-query

I'm attempting to wrap the Spotify Web API Node client with an RTK API to cache responses from the client. To do this, I was going to implement a custom baseQuery that uses the client to query the Spotify API. I'm running into some issues typing the baseQuery to restrict user inputs to just methods defined by the client. Below is the code I have so far

```
module SpotifyAPI {
  export const api = new SpotifyWebApi()

  export const isAuthenticated = () => !_.isEmpty(api.getCredentials())

  export type APIMethod = {
    [K in keyof SpotifyWebApi]: SpotifyWebApi[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? K : never
  }[keyof SpotifyWebApi]
}

interface BaseQuerySuccessReturn<T> {
  data: T,
  error?: undefined,
  meta?: { request: any, response: any }
}

interface BaseQueryErrorReturn {
  data?: undefined,
  error: { status: number, data: any },
  meta?: { request: any, response: any }
}

type BaseQueryReturn<T> = BaseQuerySuccessReturn<T> | BaseQueryErrorReturn

interface BaseQueryArgs<T extends SpotifyAPI.APIMethod> {
  method: T,
  params: Parameters<SpotifyWebApi[T]>
}

const baseQuery = async <T extends SpotifyAPI.APIMethod>(args: BaseQueryArgs<T>, {signal, dispatch, getState}, extraOptions): Promise<BaseQueryReturn<SpotifyWebApi[T]>> => {
  try {
    const response = await SpotifyAPI.api[args.method](...args.params)
    console.log(response)
    return {
      data: response
    }
  } catch (e) {
    
  }
}
```

I'd like to restrict the `args` parameter so that the `method` is a method of the SpotifyWebApi class and the `params` are an array of the expected parameters for that method. It looks like I get an error here

```
    const response = await SpotifyAPI.api[args.method](...args.params)

TS2349: This expression is not callable.   Each member of the union type '(() => Credentials) | ((credentials: Credentials) => void) | (() => void) | (() => string) | ((clientId: string) => void) | (() => void) | (() => string) | ((clientSecret: string) => void) | ... 96 more ... | { ...; }' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way for me to handle this use case in Typescript, but I'm a little lost as to what I could be doing differently.

Thanks!